# Changing password for Debian live

Tags: debian, permissions, users

I have a hooks file, in the hooks folder, that looks like this:

```
echo "root:rootpw" | chpasswd    
echo "user:userpw" | chpasswd
```

After boot, Debian asks for user and password. When I type `user` along with the password above it does NOT work. But, if I type root with the password then I can login?

After that I looked at the shadow file, but there is NO `user` in the shadow file.

```
ld config .. with username=user ..
```

Any solution?

Comment: Have you added the user `user` to the system prior to any of this? You generally use a command such as `useradd` or `adduser` to do this.

Comment: what version of debian  ?